# Lighttpd rewrite subdomains to subfolders

Tags: domain-name-system, mod-rewrite, subdomain, lighttpd, wildcard-subdomain

I have a server (itself on a subdomain) with wildcard DNS pointing to it.  The server is running Lighttpd and PHP.

I need requests to `http://any-subdomain.server.example.com` to rewrite to `http://server.example.com/site/any-subdomain` and be served from there.  It has to be completely transparent to the user.

Here's my relevant config:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^(.*)\.server\.example\.com$" {
    url.rewrite-once = ( "^(.*)" => "/site/%1/$1" )
}
```

It seems to work except for subfolders, which get redirected to `subdomain.server.example.com/site/subdomain/subfolder` and then 404's.

Comment: Do you want the user to be redirected (have their address bar change to the new address) or for them to be transparently served the content from the other domain?  Can you share the relevant current configuration?

Comment: @ShaneMadden It has to be completely transparent to the user.

Comment: So, just to confirm: you want them to be served the content from `docroot-of-server.example.com/site/subdomain` without their address bar changing, right?  You'll need to provide at least some of your current config to be able to have an answer fit into it, otherwise all we'll be able to give you is rough guidelines.

Comment: @ShaneMadden I added relevant config. And yes, I have a site folder where the subdomains should be served from. Users would have a subdomain that is exactly the same as their site subfolder.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean about the problems you're having with subdirectories?  Is `subdomain.server.example.com/site/subdomain/subfolder` a problem because it's doing the subdomain translation twice?  And where are you seeing that URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better way then using rewrites.  Instead, I used [mod_simple_vhost](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModSimpleVhost):

```
simple-vhost.server-root = "/var/www/site/"
simple-vhost.default-host = "myquick.club"
simple-vhost.document-root = "www"
```

This is a lot simpler and easier than using mod_rewrite in this case.  It was a chore to find though, I hope this helps others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

`url.rewrite-once` changes the **URL path** (and querystring); your rewrite rule looks like you're trying to rewrite to a folder on your disk.

You cannot "rewrite" the host, but you can handle two hostnames with the same physical file mapping (and fastcgi backends and ...); for example you could copy the `server.document-root` setting from the other vhost, or just make the other vhost conditional match both hostnames.

If you have "catch-all" default vhost blocks keep in mind that for each config option the last active block setting it overwrites all others (use the `-p` option to see the internal order after evaluation of `+=` and so on), so start with the default vhost(s).

Just for the record: the "relevant" config includes at least the parts for both vhosts, not just the second :)